# 403 Forbidden Error When Web Scraping MediaWorld/MediaMarket Website from Raspberry Pi with Polite package

Tags: r, web-scraping, proxy, rvest, httr

I've written a script to monitor product prices on the MediaWorld/MediaMarket website. The script fetches product details and then updates a Google spreadsheet with the results. It has been functioning correctly since March, but recently started encountering issues.

**Environment:**

The script is executed on a Raspberry Pi.
It is scheduled to run daily using a cron job.

**Problem:**

Starting yesterday, I've been receiving an HTTP 403 error. I attempted to circumvent this by rotating proxies and changing the user-agent, but these efforts were unsuccessful. Interestingly, executing the simple read_html function with the same URL works perfectly in RStudio on my PC. However, it fails with the same 403 error when run from the terminal on my Raspberry Pi.

**Code:**

```r
        #
        # ███╗░░░███╗███████╗██████╗░██╗░█████╗░  ░██╗░░░░░░░██╗░█████╗░██████╗░██╗░░░░░██████╗░
        # ████╗░████║██╔════╝██╔══██╗██║██╔══██╗  ░██║░░██╗░░██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██║░░░░░██╔══██╗
        # ██╔████╔██║█████╗░░██║░░██║██║███████║  ░╚██╗████╗██╔╝██║░░██║██████╔╝██║░░░░░██║░░██║
        # ██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══╝░░██║░░██║██║██╔══██║  ░░████╔═████║░██║░░██║██╔══██╗██║░░░░░██║░░██║
        # ██║░╚═╝░██║███████╗██████╔╝██║██║░░██║  ░░╚██╔╝░╚██╔╝░╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██████╔╝
        # ╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═════╝░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝  ░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═════╝░
        
        
        
      
    
    # Load necessary libraries
    library(tidyverse)
    library(openxlsx)
    library(lubridate)
    library(rvest)
    library(stringr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(purrr)
    library(plyr)
    library(polite)
    library(xml2)
    library(httr)
    library(data.table)
    
    # Define the URL for the MediaWorld XML feed
    mediaworld_xml_feed <- "https://www.mediaworld.it/sitemaps/sitemap-productdetailspages-000.xml"
    
    # Read the XML feed and convert it to a list
    mediaworld_rss_xml <- as_list(read_xml(mediaworld_xml_feed))
    
    # Convert the XML list to a tibble and unnest the urlset column
    xml_df <- tibble::as_tibble(mediaworld_rss_xml) %>%
      unnest_longer(urlset)
    
    # Process the XML data to create a dataframe
    lp_df <- xml_df %>%
      unnest(cols = names(.)) %>%     # unnest to release the 2-dimensional list
      unnest(cols = names(.)) %>%     # unnest the single list in each cell
      readr::type_convert()           # convert data types
    
    # Convert to dataframe and get unique URLs
    lp_df <- as.data.frame(lp_df)
    lp_df_unique <- unique(lp_df)
    lp_df_unique <- lp_df_unique$urlset
    
    # Filter for specific product types: "imetec" and "bellissima"
    lp_df_unique_df <- as.data.frame(lp_df_unique)
    lp_df_unique_2_imetec <- as.data.frame(lp_df_unique_df[lp_df_unique_df$lp_df_unique  %like% "imetec",])
    lp_df_unique_2_bellissima <- as.data.frame(lp_df_unique_df[lp_df_unique_df$lp_df_unique  %like% "bellissima",])
    
    # Extract the URLs for the two product types
    media_imetec_url <- unlist(lp_df_unique_2_imetec$`lp_df_unique_df[lp_df_unique_df$lp_df_unique %like% "imetec", ]`)
    media_bellissima_url <- unlist(lp_df_unique_2_bellissima$`lp_df_unique_df[lp_df_unique_df$lp_df_unique %like% "bellissima", ]`)
    
    # Combine the URLs into a single list
    url_media <- c(media_imetec_url, media_bellissima_url)
    
    # Define user agent list for making requests
    user_agent_list <- c(
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) ...",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) ...",
        "... other user agents ..."
    )
    
    # Define URL to fetch proxy list (which you've paid for)
    proxy_list_url <- "https://proxy.webshare.io/api/v2/proxy/list/download/urgjmvgmvimjrcnmdacddbczclyfndmqvuoxxxxx/-/any/username/direct/-/"
    
    # Fetch the proxy list
    response <- GET(proxy_list_url)
    content <- content(response, "text")
    content <- gsub("\r\n", "\n", content)
    
    # Convert the proxy list to a dataframe
    df <- read.table(
        textConnection(content),
        sep = ":",
        col.names = c("ip", "port", "username", "password")
    )
    
    # Randomly select a user agent and proxy for making the request
    ua <- sample(user_agent_list, 1, replace = FALSE)
    proxy_info <- df %>% sample_n(1)
    proxy_url <- paste0(
        "http://",
        proxy_info$username,
        ":",
        proxy_info$password,
        "@",
        proxy_info$ip,
        ":",
        proxy_info$port
    )
    proxy_config <- httr::use_proxy(proxy_url)
    
    # Use the selected user agent and proxy to fetch the data
    url <- bow(
        url_list ,
        user_agent = ua,
        force = TRUE,
        delay = 10,
        times = 10,
        verbose = TRUE,
        config = proxy_config
    )
    
    # Scrape the desired data from the fetched page
    json_data <- scrape(url, content = "text/html; charset=UTF-8", VERBOSE=TRUE) %>%
      html_nodes("script") %>%
      .[1] %>%
      html_text()
```

**Error:**

```
**Request failed [403]. Retrying in 8.5 seconds..**
```

**Additional Information:**

I've tested the functions on other websites and they work without issues.
As previously mentioned, using the simple read_html function in RStudio works as expected. However, executing the same on the Raspberry Pi returns the 403 error.
Question:
How can I potentially bypass or resolve this block?

The url that you can use is the following:

```
url_list <- "https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_asus-dual-rtx4070-o12g-nvidia-graphics-card-107303750.html"
```